# Javascript Math.log wrong result, Visual Studio

Tags: javascript, visual-studio

I'm trying to get the formula below to work but I'm getting the wrong results although I don't think there is something wrong with it.

The user types 4 numbers for exammple:

- input1 = 100
- input2 = 75
- input3 = 30
- input4 = 170

Formula:

```
var results = (Math.log(input1 + input2 - input3) / Math.log(10)) - (Math.log(input4) / Math.log(10));
```

The result is: **2.6** which is wrong.

If I change the formula like the one below it works.

```
var results = (Math.log(145) / Math.log(10)) - (Math.log(170) / Math.log(10));
```

The result is: **-0.1**

Why is that? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was nothing wrong with

```
var results = (Math.log(input1 + input2 - input3) / Math.log(10)) - (Math.log(input4) / Math.log(10));
```

The problem was here:

```
var input1 = document.getElementById("one").value;
var input2 = document.getElementById("two").value;
var input3 = document.getElementById("three").value;
var input4 = document.getElementById("four").value;
```

The numbers that the user gives are treated as strings, hence when the program runs the above formula the following will be produced:

```
var results = (Math.log(10075 - 30) / Math.log(10)) - (Math.log(170) / Math.log(10));
```

because when you add two strings in Javascript for example One + Two it will give you OneTwo.

Hence, 100 + 75 = 10075

In order to fix it I added `+` in front of `document.getElementById`.

```
var input1 = +document.getElementById("one").value;
var input2 = +document.getElementById("two").value;
var input3 = +document.getElementById("three").value;
var input4 = +document.getElementById("four").value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you might have something else causing this incorrect behavior. Both code blocks produce the same result. See the http://jsfiddle.net/Pajeh/ link.

```
var input1 = 100;
var input2 = 75;
var input3 = 30;
var input4 = 170;

var results1 = (Math.log(input1 + input2 - input3) / Math.log(10)) - (Math.log(input4) / Math.log(10));
alert(results1);

var results2 = (Math.log(145) / Math.log(10)) - (Math.log(170) / Math.log(10));
alert(results2);
```